# android: make portion of an imageview selectable

Tags: java, android, xml

How do I make part of an image view selectable with a resizable rectangle? (like the crop functionality)   .
the image view:

EDIT:
I have successfully drawn a rectangle on the image view,by using canvas. how do I make the drawn rectangle dragable by the user?

Comment: Extending BitmapDrawable might be tricky since you still need to use the ImageView to catch touch evets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to extend the ImageView. You can have a `Rect` variable in your class which you can use to determine the cropping area. Than you can override `onTouch`method to handle touch events to manipulate the cropping rectangle and override the `onDraw`to draw the cropping area over bitmap.

There is also this cropper library you can use to avoid all the hard work by the way.  https://github.com/edmodo/cropper